# Firefox browser does not open when using Selenium webdriver module

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am expecting that the below code will open Firefox browser window, but it doesn't, only prints my log sentence.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time as tm

binary = r'C:\Users\asgar\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.binary = binary

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True #optional
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path=r"C:\Users\asgar\PycharmProjects\firefoxselenium\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://google.com/")
tm.sleep(10)

print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; just change the path to 'geckodriver.exe'.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/your_path/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)


url = "https://www.google.com/"
wd.get(url)
```

Does that work?

For one thing, the 'options.headless = True' looks suspect.  Also, there may be a setting under the 3 horizontal bars (Open Menu) in the upper right hand corner of the browser that controls the behavior of new browser windows opening, so look at one of the check boxes in 'Open Menu'.